# NHibernate Performance on an internet banking application

Tags: performance, nhibernate, onlinebanking

Currently we have a project to implement an Internet Banking site, and we are evaluating using Nhibernate on it.  ¿Is NHibernate suitable for this kind of application, where performance is important and there will be a large quantity of users doing operations simultaneously?

¿Do you know any successfull stories of using NHibernate in this kind of environment?

I think NHibernate is slow only when is used incorrectly, and I think we can use it with a lot of tweaking, best practices and common sense.

UPDATE: We were contacted for the project not too long ago, and we are still collecting requirements to define the specs. The application its for a small to medium bank in our country, so they expect around a 200 - 300 users as a top simultaneously.

Im pretty sure the DB will be in SQL Server 2005, and will be a n-tier application using webservices to access the data layer.

Comment: Not NHibernate, but we've been using Hibernate for years as; the portions of our app which are are slow are universally the result of bad queries, not the framework.  So, I think you'll be fine, especially given the trivial load you're talking about.

Comment: I think that too. But I had to ask since I haven't found any good example of NHibernate being used in online banking (not that I think this is something you'll find doing a quick search on google), and my use of NHibernate is limited to applications where performance is important too, but without a large quantity of users.

Comment: Just out of curiosity what will you be doing with the database? Is this a completely new bank? I would have thought that most banking systems already had different interfaces to the data then diving straight into the database to make edits.

Comment: Well it will be used to store information about transactions, more like a log. It will also store additional information about the users of the online banking system. The bank has an existing infrastructure to access the information about the accounts stored somewhere else, in a AS/400.

Comment: I would like to know more about how you ended up developing the online banking solution. I am part of a team in my company currently analysing the concept of developing an online banking solution but this will be our first project in this area. I would appreciate any help with regards to the best way to integrate with core-banking applications. I learnt we would need to develop a middleware, how do we go about doing this. Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My team has been using NHibernate in a system requiring high throughput for years without a problem.  NH is fairly efficient to begin with, and provides fine-grained control over when and how objects are reconstituted.

With that said, we don't know the specifics of your problem, so we can't make certain predictions.  Perform scaling tests before you commit yourself.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate can be suitable if used correctly.
But, don't pin you down on this answer, since we do not know the correct specs.